# Adding a struct to mapping not working on ganache, but works in unit tests?

Tags: solidity, ganache, storage, mapping

I have this code

```
struct User {
    string name;
    string state;
    uint age;
    string[] recommendations;
    address[] following;
}

mapping(address => User) public users;
mapping(address => bool) userExists;

...

function setup(string memory _name, uint _age, string memory _state) public {
    bytes memory nameBytes = bytes(_name);
    require(nameBytes.length > 0, "Name is empty.");
    users[msg.sender] = User(_name, _state, _age, users[msg.sender].recommendations, users[msg.sender].following);
    userExists[msg.sender] = true;
}
function hasAccount() public view returns (bool) {
    return userExists[msg.sender];
}
```

Which should just add a user to the `users` mapping and add `true` to the `userExists` mapping.
This is reflected just fine in the unit test:

```
contract("Social Music", async accounts => {
const [initialAddress] = accounts;

let instance;

beforeEach(async () => {
    instance = await SocialMusic.deployed();
});

it('should set userExists after setup', async () => {
    await instance.setup('testname', 25, 'Test descr');

    const result = await instance.hasAccount();

    expect(result).to.be.true;
});
});
```

[image]

Which seems to be fine, but when I run the function `setup` in the browser, which shows up in ganache with correct params, nothing seems to be happening to the mapping afterwards.

Ganache: (FYI these are random strings)

[image]

and

[image]

Yet when calling `hasAccount` in the browser or looked at it in the ganache GUI it both seems like its not being added (browser gets `false` back when doing `const hasAcc = await socialMusicInstance.methods.hasAccount().call();`).
I have no clue whatsoever what this can be about

Comment: No its not a bug in the UI, the browser also gives me back `false` so its reflected correctly
Second doesnt answer my question

Comment: It is [bug in ganache UI](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache/issues/2164) it will not show mappings although they worked correctly underneath. Until it is fixed don't trust ganache UI display for mappings. For the other question you have to pass the account to the view function call like this `await socialMusicInstance.methods.hasAccount().call({from: "0x12341234..."})`. To check if setup worked I'd suggest to emit an event with the data, they will appear in the transaction receipt if it was successful.

Comment: Indeed seems like it, my bad there

Comment: It's fine. Sometimes my English is not good enough. We are all learning new things! Keep up the good spirit!

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that in the function `hasAccount` I am accessing `msg.sender`. It seems like this is not working in a view function, so it always returned false.